# Unknown margin in vue js application

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have generated a Vue.JS project and am having a problem.
Actually, I would like App.vue to show on the whole page and my different routes to show in **App.vue** using router-view.

However, when I try to put a margin on the content of my Game component, there seems to be a margin not on my **Game** component but on the **App** component.

Here are my two **".vue"** files below.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="bg-gray-500 h-full">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name:'App'
}
</script>

<style>
 
</style>
```

**Game.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="game">
            <div class="bg-white rounded-lg p-6 w-1/2" style="margin-top:10px">
                <h1>Hi</h1>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Game'
    }
</script>

<style>
    #game{
        margin : -0px !important;
        height: 100vh;
        top:0;
        background-color:red
    }
</style>
```

The problem is the little white bar at the top, which shouldn't be there but rather the white card which should have a margin-top of 10px[image: Problem of margin]

EDIT (main.js file):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css' 
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueCookies)
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode:'history',
  routes: [
    {path: '/home', component: require('./components/Home.vue').default},
    {path: '/', component:require('./components/Game.vue').default}
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use margin || Padding Vue.js:

```
<v-row class="mb-3"> // margin-bottom: 12px !important;
<v-row class="pt-3"> // padding-top: 12px !important;
```

Reference Link::https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#how-it-works

Answer (score 1):

In the vue.js app, the body element has a default margin of 8px.
Try to add this css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's on the `body` element rather than in your component.
Try adding `margin: 0;` to it to see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I just tried but still not

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. Also, `margin: -0px;` is not going to do anything, may as well simply set it to `margin: 0;` We would probably need to see the entire code or even better, and active example to look into it further. If possible.

Comment: I edited my post to show the last file in my project, the main.js. I have nothing else except configuration files. 
I'm also using a 'tailwindcss' CSS framework but clicking on inspect element I can't see anything that would explain this margin. That's why I think this is an issue in vue.js

Comment: It probably isn't Vue's fault to be honest, many HTML elements have default padding, margin etc. and it's probably related to that.